# How can I reference another field in a YAML fixture (possibly using ERB)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, erb, fixtures

I'm creating YAML fixtures for a Rails app and the values of several keys are linked. Is there a way to dynamically set these values based on a previous value?

I've looked into using YAML anchors and references but from what I understand they only work for whole nodes (example 2 below).

I checked the [Fixtures documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Fixtures.html) but it seems like I can only reference a fixture ID (with `Fixtures.identify(:reginald)`), not a specific value.

I assumed ERB would be the way to go but I can't figure out how to reference the other YAML values from Ruby. To make it work I had to create a block and pass in variables (example 3 below).

```
# events.yml

# Example 1 - what I currently have. It works but there is a fair bit of repetition for ~25 entries
event1:
  location: paris
  number: 34
  date: 2005-05-21
  url: "http://www.example.com/paris/subfolder/events?eventNumber=34

# Example 2 - I was hoping to be able to reference previous values by key... anchors would work if they could be interpolated somehow:
event2:
  location: &location london
  number: &number 17
  date: 2008-02-09
  url: "http://www.example.com/{{*location}}/subfolder/events?eventNumber={{*number}}

# Example 3 - This is the best I could come up with but I don't think it's an improvement to have ~25 of these blocks
<% ['paris', 46].map do |location, number| %>
event3:
  location: <%= location %>
  number: <%= number %>
  date: 2005-08-13
  url: "http://www.example.com/<%= location %>/subfolder/events?eventNumber=<%= number %>
<% end %>
```

Are there any other approaches I'm missing?

Comment: but where do you reference to other?

Comment: I repeat (reference) "location" and "number" In the URL